# Jest/Enzyme: Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined] on component wrapped in withRouter

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

So, I have a component that is wrapped in `withRouter` to access `this.props.router.query` and is generating the following error:

> `console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
>   Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined]`

How do I resolve this? My component is as follows:

```html
import { withRouter } from 'next/router';

class Order extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    const { onToken } = this.props.router.query;

    return (
      .......
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Order);
```

And my `Order.test.js` component is as follows:

```html
import Order, { SINGLE_ORDER_QUERY } from '../components/Order';
import { fakeOrder } from '../lib/testUtils';

const mocks = [
  {
    request: { query: SINGLE_ORDER_QUERY, variables: { id: 'ord123' } },
    result: { data: { order: fakeOrder() } },
  },
];

describe('<Order/>', () => {
  it('renders the order', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks}>
        <Order id="ord123" />
      </MockedProvider>
    );
    await wait();
    wrapper.update();
    const order = wrapper.find('div[data-test="order"]');
    expect(toJSON(order)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On unit tests, the router package or the `withRouter` does not have any meaning since we are testing just the component.

To fix this instead of exporting the wrapped component, you can export the individual component too:

```
import { withRouter } from 'next/router';

export class Order extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    const { onToken } = this.props.router.query;

    return (
      .......
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Order);
```

and use this instance for unit testing.

```
import { Order, SINGLE_ORDER_QUERY } from '../components/Order';
import { fakeOrder } from '../lib/testUtils';

const mocks = [
  {
    request: { query: SINGLE_ORDER_QUERY, variables: { id: 'ord123' } },
    result: { data: { order: fakeOrder() } },
  },
];

describe('<Order/>', () => {
  it('renders the order', async () => {
    const router = {
      query: {
        onToken: 1 // Whatever value you want to provide it
      }
    }
    const wrapper = mount(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks}>
        <Order id="ord123" router={router} />
      </MockedProvider>
    );
    await wait();
    wrapper.update();
    const order = wrapper.find('div[data-test="order"]');
    expect(toJSON(order)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: That great. Thank you.